# vba hash function gives #VALUE

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple hash function `ROUND(LOG(value/10,2)*13,0)` which I refer to in several places, so I tried to make it a vba function.
However using `=HASH42(cell)` or `=HASH42(number)` gives `#VALUE!`. I've tried changing `Integer` to `Double`, and putting cint around the return value without success.

```
Function HASH42(ByVal InSize As Integer) As Integer
    Dim LogSize As Double
    LogSize = Application.WorksheetFunction.Log(InSize / 10, 2)
    HASH42 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(LogSize * 13, 0)
End Function
```

I created this test function

```
Function TestHash()
    Dim Invalue As Integer
    Dim HashValue As Integer
    Invalue = 1000
    HashValue = HASH42(Invalue)
    Debug.Print Invalue & " -> " & HashValue
    TestHash = HashValue
End Function
```

Which does get the correct value from `HASH42`, when I run the debugger with varying values of `InValue`. I'm still getting `#VALUE!` in the sheet references. I have `=HASH42(1600)` in one cell to test.

Comment: Call your function from the immediate pane, what error are you getting? I suspect the actual error is "Overflow". If that's the case try changing your `Integer` declarations to `Long` to use a broader data type (`Integer` is a `short` / 16-bit signed integer, max value 32,767).

Comment: I think #NUM! would be result if you go over 32,767. Also, declaring the function as `Function HASH42(InSize)` solves some of the problems (not the best practice tho)

Comment: Set a breakpoint to the  top of the function. Now enter the formula in any cell - it should hit the breakpoint and you can use the debugger to check what is going on.